# Javascript/Node.js: ES5 child class instance accessing parent class method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to access parent's method in child's constructor as following:

***file1.js***

```
var ParentClass = function(arg) {
    this.arg = arg;
    this.result = {};
};

ParentClass.prototype = {
    constructor: ParentClass,
    isActive: function(condition) {
        return new Date(condition.valid).getTime() <= Date.now())
    }
};

module.exports = ParentClass;
```

***file2.js***

```
var ParentClass = require('file1');

var ChildClass= function(arg) {
    ParentClass.apply(this, arguments);
    this.init();
};

ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);
ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;

ChildClass.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        this.result = this.arg.validity
        .filter(function(elem) {
            return this.isActive(elem)
        }.bind(this));
    }
}

module.exports = ChildClass;
```

***file3.js***

```
var ChildClass= require('file2.js');
var instance = new ChildClass(param);
```

initializing such instance gives me

```
TypeError: this.isActive is not a function
  at Object.<anonymous> (file2.js)
  at Array.filter (native)
  at Object.ChildClass.init (file2.js)
```

Help and explanation appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is `this.arg.validity` an object or an array? What is purpose of `ParentClass.apply(this, arguments)`?

Comment: You are not using `Object.create` properly. According to the docs, it creates an object whose **prototype** is equal to the object you pass in. So to access it, you would have to say `ChildClass.prototype.__proto__`, or you can say `ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype).__proto__`. You are also redefining `ChildClass.prototype` as a new object, rather than just defining the init method on it. Do you mean to say `ChildClass.prototype.init = function() { ... }`?

Comment: @guest271314 - That calls the constructor of the parent class with whatever arguments were passed to the constructor.

Comment: @guest271314 `this.arg.validity` it is array of objects. `apply` in this case just sets `this.arg = arg;` in child class instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two separate assignments to `ChildClass.prototype`.  One will override the other.  Instead, you need to first initialize your prototype with `Object.create()` as you are doing and then you need to ADD new methods to it, not assign to the whole prototype, thus replacing everything you just put there.

These are the two conflicting statements:

```
ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);

ChildClass.prototype = {...};
```

One common way to fix this is to use `Object.assign()` to copy your methods onto the existing prototype:

```
Object.assign(ChildClass.prototype, {
    init: function() {
        this.result = this.arg.validity
        .filter(function(elem) {
            return this.isActive(elem)
        }.bind(this));
    }
});
```

This will copy each of your methods over to the already existing prototype object and this method is more commonly used when you have lots of methods.

You can also just assign the new methods one at a time (more commonly used when you have just a few methods):

```
ChildClass.prototype.init = function() {
    this.result = this.arg.validity.filter(function(elem) {
        return this.isActive(elem)
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: @leela - ES6 class syntax makes this so much simpler to write (though it generates the exact same result internally).

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining ChildClass.prototype as a new object, which overwrites your assignment using `Object.create()` a few lines prior. Instead, simply define the init method on it.

Try this:

```js
var ParentClass = function(arg) {
  this.arg = arg;
  this.result = {};
};

ParentClass.prototype = {
  constructor: ParentClass,
  isActive: function(condition) {
    return new Date(condition.valid).getTime() <= Date.now();
  }
};

var ChildClass = function(arg) {
  ParentClass.apply(this, arguments);
  this.init();
};

ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);
ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;
ChildClass.prototype.init = function() {
  this.result = this.arg.validity
    .filter(function(elem) {
      return this.isActive(elem);
    }.bind(this));
};


var instance = new ChildClass({
  validity: [{
    valid: "01/01/17"
  }]
});

console.log(instance);
```